# TabHost with Multiple ViewFlippers - GestureListener

Tags: android, listview, android-tabhost, viewflipper, gesture

I have a TabHost that has two ViewFlippers, and inside each ViewFlipper are three ListViews. I would like to have left<->right gesture listener for the ViewFlipper to slide between the three ListViews. The Up/Down motion for the ListViews seems to work, but I cannot seem to get the ViewFlipper to work.

[image: SessionView]

Sessions.java (TabActivity)

```
public class Sessions extends TabActivity {

    private Guide guide;
    private String LOG_TAG = "Sessions Activity";

    // TabHost
    private TabHost tabhost;
    private ViewFlipper viewFlipperDay0;
    private ViewFlipper viewFlipperDay1;
    private TextView trackTitle_day0;
    private TextView trackTitle_day1;
    private GestureDetector gestureDetectorDay0;
    private GestureDetector gestureDetectorDay1;
    private ListView lv_day0_trackA;
    private ListView lv_day0_trackB;
    private ListView lv_day0_trackC;
    private ListView lv_day1_trackA;
    private ListView lv_day1_trackB;
    private ListView lv_day1_trackC;

    private ArrayList<Session> sessionList_day0_trackA;
    private ArrayList<Session> sessionList_day0_trackB;
    private ArrayList<Session> sessionList_day0_trackC;
    private ArrayList<Session> sessionList_day1_trackA;
    private ArrayList<Session> sessionList_day1_trackB;
    private ArrayList<Session> sessionList_day1_trackC;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Bundle b = this.getIntent().getExtras();
        if (b!=null) {
            this.guide = (Guide) b.getSerializable(GUIDETYPE);
            Log.d(LOG_TAG,"Got guide through intent Serializable");
        } else {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG,"Unable to get guide through Intent");
        }
        setContentView(R.layout.sessions);

        this.trackTitle_day0 = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.session_track_desc_day0);
        this.trackTitle_day0.setText("Track A");
        this.viewFlipperDay0 = (ViewFlipper) this.findViewById(R.id.session_viewflipper_day0);
        this.trackTitle_day1 = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.session_track_desc_day1);
        this.trackTitle_day1.setText("Track A");
        this.viewFlipperDay1 = (ViewFlipper) this.findViewById(R.id.session_viewflipper_day1);

        this.gestureDetectorDay0 = new GestureDetector(new SessionGestureDetector(this.viewFlipperDay0));
        this.gestureDetectorDay1 = new GestureDetector(new SessionGestureDetector(this.viewFlipperDay1));

        // set up gesture swiping of tracks with animations (left/right only)
        //    up/down events and those which are too diagonal or squigly are ignored
        viewFlipperDay0.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
        {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (gestureDetectorDay0.onTouchEvent(event)) {
                 return true;
                } else {
                 return false;
                }
            }
        });
        viewFlipperDay1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
        {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (gestureDetectorDay1.onTouchEvent(event)) {
                 return true;
                } else {
                 return false;
                }
            }
        });

        // load views into viewflipper
        /// Add Tracks
        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"Creating Track Views");
        View view_day0_trackA = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.session_track, null);
        View view_day0_trackB = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.session_track, null);
        View view_day0_trackC = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.session_track, null);
        View view_day1_trackA = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.session_track, null);
        View view_day1_trackB = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.session_track, null);
        View view_day1_trackC = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.session_track, null);

        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"Adding Track Views to ViewFlippers");
        addViewToDayFlipper0(view_day0_trackA);
        addViewToDayFlipper0(view_day0_trackB);
        addViewToDayFlipper0(view_day0_trackC);
        addViewToDayFlipper1(view_day1_trackA);
        addViewToDayFlipper1(view_day1_trackB);
        addViewToDayFlipper1(view_day1_trackC);

        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"Assigning ListViews");
        this.lv_day0_trackA = (ListView) view_day0_trackA.findViewById(R.id.SessionListView);
        this.lv_day0_trackB = (ListView) view_day0_trackB.findViewById(R.id.SessionListView);
        this.lv_day0_trackC = (ListView) view_day0_trackC.findViewById(R.id.SessionListView);
        this.lv_day1_trackA = (ListView) view_day1_trackA.findViewById(R.id.SessionListView);
        this.lv_day1_trackB = (ListView) view_day1_trackB.findViewById(R.id.SessionListView);
        this.lv_day1_trackC = (ListView) view_day1_trackC.findViewById(R.id.SessionListView);
        //http://pareshnmayani.wordpress.com/tag/android-custom-listview-example/

        // get sessions
        //this.guide = this.getGuide();
        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"Getting Session info for each track");
        this.sessionList_day0_trackA = guide.getSessionsByTrack(0,0);
        this.sessionList_day0_trackB = guide.getSessionsByTrack(0,1);
        this.sessionList_day0_trackC = guide.getSessionsByTrack(0,2);
        this.sessionList_day1_trackA = guide.getSessionsByTrack(1,0);
        this.sessionList_day1_trackB = guide.getSessionsByTrack(1,1);
        this.sessionList_day1_trackC = guide.getSessionsByTrack(1,2);

        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"Assigning SessionAdapters");
        final SessionListAdapter lv_day0_trackA_adapter = new SessionListAdapter(this, this.sessionList_day0_trackA);
        final SessionListAdapter lv_day0_trackB_adapter = new SessionListAdapter(this, this.sessionList_day0_trackB);
        final SessionListAdapter lv_day0_trackC_adapter = new SessionListAdapter(this, this.sessionList_day0_trackC);
        final SessionListAdapter lv_day1_trackA_adapter = new SessionListAdapter(this, this.sessionList_day1_trackA);
        final SessionListAdapter lv_day1_trackB_adapter = new SessionListAdapter(this, this.sessionList_day1_trackB);
        final SessionListAdapter lv_day1_trackC_adapter = new SessionListAdapter(this, this.sessionList_day1_trackC);

        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"Setting Adapters");
        lv_day0_trackA.setAdapter(lv_day0_trackA_adapter);
        lv_day0_trackB.setAdapter(lv_day0_trackB_adapter);
        lv_day0_trackC.setAdapter(lv_day0_trackC_adapter);
        lv_day1_trackA.setAdapter(lv_day1_trackA_adapter);
        lv_day1_trackB.setAdapter(lv_day1_trackB_adapter);
        lv_day1_trackC.setAdapter(lv_day1_trackC_adapter);

        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"ListView OnClickListenters being assigned");
        lv_day0_trackA.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long id) {
                // item click listener for listview
                Session session = (Session) lv_day0_trackA_adapter.getItem(position);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Title => "+session.getTitle()+" \n Time => "+session.getTimeSpan(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        });
        lv_day0_trackB.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long id) {
                // item click listener for listview
                Session session = (Session) lv_day0_trackB_adapter.getItem(position);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Title => "+session.getTitle()+" \n Time => "+session.getTimeSpan(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        });
        lv_day0_trackC.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long id) {
                // item click listener for listview
                Session session = (Session) lv_day0_trackC_adapter.getItem(position);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Title => "+session.getTitle()+" \n Time => "+session.getTimeSpan(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        });
        lv_day1_trackA.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long id) {
                // item click listener for listview
                Session session = (Session) lv_day1_trackA_adapter.getItem(position);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Title => "+session.getTitle()+" \n Time => "+session.getTimeSpan(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        });
        lv_day1_trackB.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long id) {
                // item click listener for listview
                Session session = (Session) lv_day1_trackB_adapter.getItem(position);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Title => "+session.getTitle()+" \n Time => "+session.getTimeSpan(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        });
        lv_day1_trackC.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long id) {
                // item click listener for listview
                Session session = (Session) lv_day1_trackC_adapter.getItem(position);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Title => "+session.getTitle()+" \n Time => "+session.getTimeSpan(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        });

        tabhost = getTabHost();
        tabhost.getTabWidget().setDividerDrawable(R.drawable.tab_divider);
        tabhost.addTab(tabhost.newTabSpec("day0").setIndicator(createTabView(tabhost.getContext(), "Friday")).setContent(R.id.session_tab_layout_day0));
        tabhost.addTab(tabhost.newTabSpec("day1").setIndicator(createTabView(tabhost.getContext(), "Saturday")).setContent(R.id.session_tab_layout_day1));
        tabhost.setCurrentTab(0);

        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"Finished?");
    };

    private static View createTabView(final Context context, final String text) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.tabs_bg, null);
        TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tabsText);
        tv.setText(text);
        return view;
    }


    // Add view to viewflipper
    public void addViewToDayFlipper0(View view) {
        viewFlipperDay0.addView(view);
    }
    public void addViewToDayFlipper1(View view) {
        viewFlipperDay1.addView(view);
    }

    // Custom Gesture Adapter
    public class SessionGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

          private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 120;
          private static final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 250;
          private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;
          private ViewFlipper vf;

          public SessionGestureDetector(final ViewFlipper vf) {
              super();
              this.vf = vf;
          }

          public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
           System.out.println(" in onFling() :: ");
           if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH)
            return false;
           if (e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
             && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
            vf.setInAnimation(inFromRightAnimation());
            vf.setOutAnimation(outToLeftAnimation());
            vf.showNext();
           } else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
             && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
            vf.setInAnimation(inFromLeftAnimation());
            vf.setOutAnimation(outToRightAnimation());
            vf.showPrevious();
           }
           return super.onFling(e1, e2, velocityX, velocityY);
          }
        }

    private Animation inFromRightAnimation() {
        Animation inFromRight = new TranslateAnimation(
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, +1.0f,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f);
        inFromRight.setDuration(500);
        inFromRight.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
        return inFromRight;
    }

    private Animation outToLeftAnimation() {
        Animation outtoLeft = new TranslateAnimation(
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, -1.0f,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f);
        outtoLeft.setDuration(500);
        outtoLeft.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
        return outtoLeft;
    }

    private Animation inFromLeftAnimation() {
        Animation inFromLeft = new TranslateAnimation(
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, -1.0f,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f);
        inFromLeft.setDuration(500);
        inFromLeft.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
        return inFromLeft;
    }

    private Animation outToRightAnimation() {
        Animation outtoRight = new TranslateAnimation(
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, +1.0f,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f);
        outtoRight.setDuration(500);
        outtoRight.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
        return outtoRight;
    }
}
```

sessions.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="#222222">       
        <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/session_tab_layout_day0"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:background="#F0E0B2">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#8e9f13"
                    android:background="#006772"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:id="@+id/session_track_desc_day0"
                    android:text="@string/session_track"></TextView>
                <ViewFlipper
                    android:id="@+id/session_viewflipper_day0"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                </ViewFlipper>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/session_tab_layout_day1"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:background="#F0E0B2">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#8e9f13"
                    android:background="#006772"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:id="@+id/session_track_desc_day1"
                    android:text="@string/session_track"></TextView>
                <ViewFlipper
                    android:id="@+id/session_viewflipper_day1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                </ViewFlipper>
            </LinearLayout>
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

session_track.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/session_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#F0E0B2">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/SessionListView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

session_two_line_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="70dip"
  android:padding="6dip">
    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/session_title"
      android:text="Session Title"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:gravity="center_vertical"
      android:textSize="22dip"
      android:textColor="#006772"/>
    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/session_time"
      android:text="08:00-09:00"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:singleLine="true"
      android:textSize="13dip"
      android:textColor="#006772" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a ViewFlipper, use a [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html). It's a relatively late addition to the SDK that was created for exactly this sort of GUI.

Comment: Took a while to wrap my head around ViewPager, but it certainly did the job perfectly! Thanks!